# <BrowserRouter> Does not remove hashbang from route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

There is a `#/` (hashbang) in my react route...

searching online yeilds covering `<Route>` with the new `<BrowserRouter>` will fix the problem

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.scss';

import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import { Header } from './components/Header'
import { Footer } from './components/Footer';
import { Route , BrowserRouter , Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import MainState from './components/appset/MainState';

import HomePage from './components/HomePage';
import { TestContent } from './components/TestContent';
import { Account } from './components/Account';
import { TokenList } from './components/TokenList';
import { TokenPage } from './components/TokenPage';
import ErrorPage from './components/ErrorPage';


class Layout extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="bodyWheel" className={`App ${MainState.currentTheme} ${MainState.currentLang}`}>
        <Header />

        <div id="App-intro" className={this.state.resolutionHeight}>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="layout-main">
              <BrowserRouter>
                <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
                <Route path="/test" component={TestContent} />
                <Route path="/account/:id" exact component={Account} />
                <Route path="/token" exact component={TokenPage} />
                <Route path="/token/:id" exact component={TokenList} />
                <Route path="/operation/:id" exact component={HomePage}/>
                <Route path="/error/:id" exact component={ErrorPage} />
              </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Layout;
```

It adds #/ by itself at the end of every route for example:

`www.foo.com/account/tera`
becomes 
`www.foo.come/account/tera#/`

`<BrowserRouter>` did nothing at all.

Will building and uploading to a webserver instead of running on 'npm start' fix the problem?

(edit:) turns out `<BrowserRouter> works but something just keeps adding`#/`to the end of my routes the routs without`#/` works just fine

Comment: Can you show the part of the code that has the `<Link>` component?

Comment: it is in the header
    `<div className="title-logo">
        <Link to="/"><img src={MainState.currentTheme === 'theme-light' ? LogoLight : LogoDark} alt="main logo" /></Link>
    </div>`

but even if you type the link in yourself somthing manages to add in a `#/` itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix is in the `<BrowserRouter>` edit to `<BrowserRouter basename="">`

and cover the main div

```
<BrowserRouter basename="">
   <div id="bodyWheel" className={`App ${MainState.currentTheme} ${MainState.currentLang}`}>
   ....
   </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

fixed all the routing problems!